# MySQL Same Day Last Year

Tags: mysql, sql

Arguments about start/end of week aside, how do you get a query that selects from the same table to compare a number this week versus the same week last year?

Every time I try, the number gets inflated because it is doing a cross product type thing.

Something like

```
SELECT 
DATE(t1.`date`) AS 'Date', SUM(t1.`sold`), SUM(t2.`sold`)
FROM `table` AS t1
JOIN `table` AS t2 ON WEEK(t1.`date`) = WEEK(t2.`date`)
WHERE WEEK(t1.`date`) = WEEK(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(t1.`date`) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(t2.`date`) = YEAR(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL - 1 YEAR))
GROUP BY DATE(t1.`date`)
```

Comment: Will you add your schema for the associated tables to the question?

Comment: Are you trying to get a total for (e.g.) week 1 2012 vs week 1 2011, where the `sold` can be daily?

Comment: You should also provide current example data AND the result table you are expecting to get

Answer (score 2):

How about the following?

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test;
+------------+------+
| date       | sold |
+------------+------+
| 2012-02-10 |  100 |
| 2012-02-10 |  200 |
| 2011-02-10 |   50 |
| 2011-02-10 |   25 |
+------------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->     CONCAT(WEEK(date), "-", YEAR(date)), SUM(sold)
    -> FROM
    ->     test
    -> WHERE
    ->     WEEK(`date`) = WEEK(NOW()) 
    ->     AND (YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(NOW()) OR YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL - 1 YEAR))) 
    -> GROUP BY 
    ->     YEAR(date), WEEK(date);
+-------------------------------------+-----------+
| CONCAT(WEEK(date), "-", YEAR(date)) | SUM(sold) |
+-------------------------------------+-----------+
| 6-2011                              |        75 |
| 6-2012                              |       300 |
+-------------------------------------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend @MartinJansen's answer - MySQL works a lot better row-wise than column-wise, *especially* when you only want to extract a specific week.

However, if you wanted it column-wise or if you wanted it for more than one specific week, you could try:

```
mysql> SELECT * from sales;
+------------+------+
| date       | sold |
+------------+------+
| 2011-01-01 |    1 |
| 2011-01-02 |   10 |
| 2011-01-03 |    3 |
| 2012-01-01 |   10 |
| 2012-01-02 |   20 |
+------------+------+

SELECT CONCAT('week',WEEK(t.`date`)) as week, 
 SUM(IF(YEAR(t.`date`)=YEAR(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL - 1 YEAR)),t.sold,0)) as `2011`, 
 SUM(IF(YEAR(t2.`date`)=YEAR(NOW()),t2.sold,0)) as `2012`
FROM sales t
LEFT JOIN sales t2
ON t.date = t2.date     --could add WHERE WEEK(t.date)=... to restrict week
GROUP BY WEEK(t.date)

+-------+------+------+
| week  | 2011 | 2012 |
+-------+------+------+
| week0 |    1 |    0 |
| week1 |   13 |   30 |
+-------+------+------+
```

(You'll have to read up on MySQL's exact definition of weeks).